# Domain Logic in an Entity Component System

Tags: entity-component-system

Where to put the domain logic in an Entity Component System?

For sure you will not put it onto the Entity (number) itself but you can implement it as method on the Component but also as Method on the System. However, if put on the Component there might be the problem of validating across several Components and on the other hand when applied as System part there is the issue of possible duplication due to having multiple Systems adressing the same set of Entities.

This leads me to the point that there is some kind of domain logic handler required but who is calling it? It must be ensured to be called. Any Architecutral proposals/patterns here?

Comment: In pure ECS, components don't and can't (and shouldn't) have methods. ALL logic is inside systems (and helpers/libraries, called from systems). Can you give me an example of what kind of logic you mean? Validation for example? For that I would create validation system. Result of the validation could be another component, for example InvalidName, or just Invalid(with a list of errors). Then your UI system would go through all Invalid components and show them on screen (in GUI app) or add them to response (in HTTP app). You can have multiple validation systems, too, like healthValidationSystem.